# use multiple variable with brace expression in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, brace-expansion

This works fine :-

```
for i in host{1..4} host2{1..4}
do
    echo $i
done
```

Now,

I have two variable likes this :-

`host=host{1..4}`

`host2=host2{1..4}`

how do i use this two variable in above loop so both work same?

something like this :-

```
for i in $host $host2
do
    echo $i
done
```

any help is appriciated

Comment: You cannot delay the brace expansion until that point, it will happen as part of variable assignment itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use eval:

```
$ for i in `eval echo $host $host2`;do echo $i;done
host1
host2
host3
host4
host21
host22
host23
host24
```